# It is good for health ________ us to get up early

Tags: prepositions

It is good for health ________ us to get up early.

a. for 
b. of

Someone posted this question in our Q/A board (we are non native). We don't know which answer is correct.
I think the answer is 'of' but others say the answer is 'for'.
What is the answer in this sentence?

It will be easy if the sentences are the following:

> It is good for us to get up early. 
>   It is good for health to get up early. 
>   It is good for our health to get up early.

But this sentence has both 'us' and 'health'.

I think '**for** health **for** us (double for)' sounds somewhat awkward to me. So I think the anwer is 'of' (for health of us)
but someone says if you use 'of' the sentence should have 'the' (for the health of us). Is 'the' necessary if I use 'of'?

So what is the answer? (He had originally posted this question and already chose the answer as 'for', but I still wonder if the answer is 'of'. Am I wrong?

Comment: Few people would phrase it like that - not least because the two occurrences of ***for*** sound a bit clunky (and ***of*** is probably "ungrammatical" anyway). Normal phrasing would be *It is healthy [for us] to get up early* (where ***for us*** would usually be omitted).

Comment: Is this sentence taken from a book or website? Can you provide the source?

Comment: I prefer to use "our health" rather "health of us", by the way

Comment: I also find the phrasing "It is good for health" to be a little stilted.  "It is good for *our* health" or "*one's* health" or "*the* health" sounds better to my ear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to try a "socractic" answer by answering with a question.

Let's look at the sentence with the pieces of the predication reversed and without the so-called "dummy" or "expletive" It:

**________ us to get up early is good for health.**

The predicate: "is".

The predicate complement:  {good for (our) health}.

The subject-phrase:  {________ us to get up early}.

So now which works better there?

> **Of** us to get up early is good for our health.
>
> **For** us to get up early is good for our health.